# Creating a list of objects from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

So first of all I have a function that count words in a text file, and a program that creates a dictionary based on how many occurences of the word is in that text file. The program is

```
def counter (AllWords):
    d = {}
    for word in AllWords:
        if word in d.keys():
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1
    return d;

f = open("test.txt", "r")
AllWords = []

for word in f.read().split():
    AllWords.append(word.lower())

print(counter(AllWords))
```

Now given that dictionary, I want to create a list of objects such that the objects will have two instance variables, the word (string) and how many time it appears (integer). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
list(d.items())
```

It will create a list of tuples like:

```
[('Foo',3),('Bar',2)]
```

Or you can define your own class:

```
class WordCount:

    def __init__(self,word,count):
        self.word = word
        self.count = count
```

and use list comprehension:

```
[WordCount(*item) for item in d.items()]
```

So here you create a list of `WordCount` objects.

Nevertheless, your `counter(..)` method is actually not necessary: Python already has a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
```

which is "a dictionary with things" so to speak: you can simply construct it like:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(allWords)
```

Comment: Hi, I want to use defining my own class method but I'm not quite sure what's going on. Lets say I have a dictionary 

    d = { "this" : 5, "is" : 7, "wrong" : 8}

Comment: Hi, I want to use defining my own class method but I'm not quite sure what's going on. Lets say I have a dictionary 

    d = { "this" : 5, "is" : 7, "wrong" : 8}

and we define our class 

    class WordCount():
             def __init__(self, word, count):
                   self.word = word
                   self.count = count
    list_obj = [WordCount(*item) for item in d.items()]
    print(list_obj)

But this doesnt produce a list? I'm sorry I just started with class and objects and having a hard time getting it.

Comment: The `list_obj` is a list, a list of `WordCount` items. It is constructed by *list comprehension*. You can check the type with `type(list_obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent to wheel to count items.

What about a quasi one-liner to do all the heavy lifting, using of course `collections.Counter` and the mighty `str.split` ?

```
import collections

with open("text.txt") as f:
    c = collections.Counter(f.read().split())
```

Now `c` contains the couples: word,number of occurences of the word